# Set expiry in Azure key vault secret

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

How to set expires in key vault while setting secret using azure cli. I tried the following but it didn't work. Any help is highly appreciable.

```
az keyvault secret set --name <my-key> --value <my-value> --vault-name <my-kv> --expires "2018-12-30T07:28:38Z"
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "created": "2018-12-13T07:45:37+00:00",
    "enabled": true,
    "expires": null,
    "notBefore": null,
    "recoveryLevel": "Purgeable",
    "updated": "2018-12-13T07:45:37+00:00"
  },
  "contentType": null,
  "id": "https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/<mykey>/<version>",
  "kid": null,
  "managed": null,
  "tags": {
    "file-encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "value": "<myvalue>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick update: Finally MS fixed the issue on August 27, 2019 in azure CLI release Version **2.0.72**. Once you update your CLI, you will be all set.

- [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8052)
- [Release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#keyvault)

Answer (score 3):

Try the command [`az keyvault secret set-attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set-attributes), it works on my side.

```
az keyvault secret set-attributes --vault-name 'keyvaultname' --name 'test' --expires '2018-12-30T07:28:38Z'
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried this but I don't want to update, I want this to happen while creating the secret.Surprisingly as per specification  the same option is not working with set. I think it's a bug.

Comment: @lambodar Agree with you, it may be a bug, I think you could post the issue in the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md), besides, I think my reply actually solve the issue, could you mark it as answer?

Comment: yes I did mate, thanks for your support. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8052

Comment: @lambodar Could you mark it, mate?Not the upvote, thanks.

Comment: But the answer is still in puzzle. I'll post the answer once heard back from MS team. I didn't get what I was looking for yet, I don't have any issue in marking but if I will mark, it might mislead others.

Comment: @lambodar If you mark it, I think it will help more community members who has the same issue with you, if the MS replies the issue in the github, you could just post another answer under mine, right? I have met the similar issue before, I think it will be fine. Also I think they will notice the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185199/discussion-between-lambodar-and-joy-wang).